# Averages of active records

Tags: r, time-series

How would I find the averages of active observations for each day in six month period. The data looks like this:

```
output  start       end
12000   04/01/2012  04/01/2012
2175    11/25/2011  01/22/2012
1800    12/06/2011  01/23/2012
1795    03/23/2012  03/23/2012
1550    04/03/2012  04/20/2012
3400    10/13/2011  01/24/2012
1850    02/27/2012  03/08/2012
2500    11/08/2011  01/24/2012
5350    02/02/2012  04/01/2012
2550    02/09/2012  04/09/2012
8000    11/01/2011  01/22/2012
2725    12/02/2011  01/22/2012
6249    01/12/2012  01/24/2012
1875    01/22/2012  02/28/2012
2550    01/18/2012  01/24/2012
2650    01/28/2012  01/29/2012
2100    11/25/2011  02/21/2012
6900    01/17/2012  02/17/2012
1779    04/21/2012  04/21/2012
4900    11/09/2011  01/22/2012
3250    12/09/2011  01/24/2012
2995    03/14/2012  04/18/2012
```

So for each day within the six months, I want to find the the average of all active observations on that day. For example, the second observation above would be included in the with all other active observations to find the averages on the days between 11/25/2011 and 01/22/2012.

any insights on how to pull it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start <- as.Date(data$start, "%m/%d/%Y")
end <- as.Date(data$end, "%m/%d/%Y")
period <- as.Date(min(start):max(end), origin = "1970-01-01")
averages <- sapply(period, function(x) mean(data[x >= start & x <= end, 'output']))
data.frame(period, averages)
```

Comment: When I tried "averages", I get:    
Error in mean(data[x >= start & x <= end, "output"]) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': Error in data[x >= start & x <= end, "output"] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: There must be something wrong with your data variable, data <- read.table("1.txt", header=T, quote="\"") is how I loaded it